# How to declare the type of a loop variable

Tags: loops, common-lisp, type-declaration

I want to do some integer arithmetic and was checking if SBCL could gain more speed if I provide explicit information about the `type` of values I use. While I easily could use `declare` in a `defun` or `let` directly to do so, I do not understand where to put the statement within a `loop` construct.

I came across the documentation of the `iterate` package which offers such possibilities but wanted to stick to loop for the moment.

A stub example could look like this:

```
(loop :for i from 1 upto 100 :collect
  (loop :for j from i upto 100
    :collect (* i j)))
```

How can I tell Lisp that `i` and `j` are e.g. of type `fixnum`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For simple types like `fixnum`, `float`, `t` and `nil` you can just write the type after the variable in the FOR clause. You can also add a type in a *numeric-accumulation clause* like a `sum` clause:

```
(loop for i fixnum below 10
      for j fixnum from 1 
      sum (* i j) fixnum)
```

Comment: Omitting `of-type` makes code concise, but, IMO, *less* readable.

Comment: @sds: I use that all the time. Since only FIXNUM and FLOAT make some sense for the short notation, I don't see any readability problem. The OF-TYPE notation is relatively rare in code I've seen.

Comment: I bow to you experience :-)

Comment: @sds: just looking at some applications, for fixnum declarations, with `of-type` is used a lot, but definitely less than declarations without `of-type`.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`of-type`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_loop.htm):

```
(loop :for i of-type fixnum from 1 upto 100 :collect
  (loop :for j of-type fixnum from i upto 100
    :collect (* i j)))
```

Also, [Examples of WITH clause](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_abba.htm) are nice.

Like Rainer said, you can omit `of-type` for simple types,
e.g., [`fixnum`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_fixnum.htm)
and [`float`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_float.htm),
but that violates the "rhythm" of `loop` whereby `loop` keywords
alternate with user forms.

Note also that declaring `i` and `j` to be `fixnum`s is **not** enough
to ensure `fixnum` multiplication (the square
of [`most-positive-fixnum`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_most_p.htm) is
certainly *not* a `fixnum`). Thus to get the fastest possible
multiplication you would need to declare `i` and `j` to be
[`(unsigned-byte 1000)`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_unsgn_.htm) which
*does* require `of-type`.

Of course, all this should not be necessary.
The compiler **should** be smart enough. :-)